# Excluding whole frames with ifthen does not work (any more...)

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I have a large slide deck (a multi-day training course) from which I want to generate different training courses (different lengths and combinations of subjects) by including/excluding certain slides. I used to do this with ifthen, but all of a sudden (new computer) it fails. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newif\ifdetails
\newcommand{\details}[1]{\ifdetails#1\fi}
\detailstrue

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{No Problems Here}
\details{Works fine, really.}
\end{frame}

\details{
\begin{frame}[fragile]{But Issues Here}
Why??!?
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Again, All Good}
\details{Works fine, again.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This works fine when `\detailstrue` is not set, but otherwise fails with

```
(./demo1.vrb
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endframe ->\egroup 
                    \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.2 Why??!? \end {frame}
                         \fi
```

(As you can see, it only fails for the `\details{}` command that is wrapped around a frame. The ones used inside a frame are perfectly fine.)

From googling I learned that I should rather use etoolbox, so I replaced the `\details` definition by:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{details}
\newcommand{\details}[1]{\ifbool{details}{#1}{}}
\booltrue{details}
```

This also works well when `\newbool{details}` is not present, but again fails otherwise:

```
(./demo2.vrb
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endframe ->\egroup 
                    \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.2 Why??!? \end {frame}
```

I finally tried to leverage Beamer's own mechanism for hiding frames and defined my own environment for this:

```
\newenvironment{frameOn}[2]{\ifbool{#1}{\begin{frame}[fragile]{#2}}{\begin{frame}<0>[noframenumbering]{}}}{\end{frame}}

...

\begin{frameOn}{details}{But Issues Here}
Why??!?
\end{frameOn}
```

Again, all is well when the boolean flag is not set, but the same failure occurs otherwise:

```
(./demo3.vrb
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endframe ->\egroup 
                    \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.3 \end{frameOn}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? How can I exclude full slides programmatically? Thanks for any insights :-)

Comment: Works without the `[fragile]`, so has something to do with that.

Comment: Why do you want all frames to be `fragile`? You should only use that with verbatim content.

Comment: You can't do this with fragile frames. You can try `\ifdetails` ... `\fi` instead but imho you should better implement such a switch with mode specifications. Btw: Your command doesn't use the ifthen package, that's a low-level \if.

Comment: @TeXnician: I actually use lstlisting a lot (these are programming trainings). So I usually need [fragile].

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: "You can't do this with fragile frames." -- The weird thing is: This worked 6 weeks ago (as I said, I have a large slide deck and I extracted a subset from it in October, using the initial definition of `\details` I gave above). I'm a bit dumbfounded on what happened to LaTeX that made it not work any more...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: "BTW: Your command doesn't use the ifthen package" -- Thanks for the hint, that's what happens when I copy/paste stuff from somewhere ;-)

Comment: Your minimal example doesn't work back to texlive 2013. So whyever it worked, it wasn't due to something in latex. Probably you changed your document. Excluding large portions of text is not trivial.

Comment: The manual says that \end{frame} must be alone in a line by itself, but when passed as an argument the spaces get eaten.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Now I'm getting curious... I will go back to the other computer and see if I can figure out why it worked there. (but I can only do this at the end of next month, so don't expect any updates here soon...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to turn off a frame.

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}

%\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newif\ifdetails
\newcommand{\details}[1]{\ifdetails#1\fi}
\detailstrue

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{No Problems Here}
\details{Works fine, really.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<\ifdetails1-\else0\fi>[fragile]{But Issues Here}
Why??!?
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Again, All Good}
\details{Works fine, again.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what Ulrike hinted at -- thank you for elaborating!

Comment: Is that a mode specification?  I thought I was specifying overlays.